# How to use SetPasswordForm in a FormView

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am using Django's own `SetPasswordForm()` form class so I can allow a user to reset a password without providing their old one.

My view is below:

```
class UserSetPassword(FormView):
    template_name = 'accounts/users/user_set_password.html'
    form_class = SetPasswordForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('user_list')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, 'Initial password set')
        return super(UserSetPassword, self).form_valid(form)
```

However this results in the error:

```
TypeError at /users/set_password/
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: *".... without providing their old one"* What you mean? Can you elaborate on your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SetPasswordForm()` requires you to pass the user that you are setting the password for as an argument. You can do this by using the `get_form_kwargs` method which will return a dictionary with the `kwargs` that will be passed to the `__init__` of your form, which will inject the user in your case. See an example here https://www.pydanny.com/adding-django-form-instance-attributes.html